# Stateless NAT with Linux

Tags: linux, networking, nat

There seems to be some rumors floating around that stateless NAT exists in linux in a non-depreciated form (unlike iproute2) as of 2.6.24:

http://lwn.net/Articles/254559/
http://www.mail-archive.com/netdev@vger.kernel.org/msg53070.html
...

However, I can't find any documentation on how this might work.  Anyone have an idea of how this works?

Comment: Zow, the documentation for `tc` looks sparse! The `tc` action `nat egress 10.7.0.5/32 12.12.12.5` (assuming 10.7.0.5 is the private IP and 12.12.12.5 is the public IP) will do what you want, but getting the packets classified to allow the nat action to apply looks like more than I can glean from reading. W/o having the tools at hand I think that's the best I can say.

Comment: Ya, I think I am just going to go with the NO nat for the important stuff.  It just didn't cross my mind that I could still NAT address even if they were assigned to an interface since the NAT is pre routing.

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure [`iproute2`](http://www.linuxfoundation.org/collaborate/workgroups/networking/iproute2) has been deprecated?

See [this doc](http://linux-ip.net/html/nat-stateless.html).

Comment: Yes I should have linked to that in my question. I was using that and the ip command shoots back a depreciation warning.

Comment: That doc also links to how to emulate stateless NAT with netfilter ... from what I can tell the author just made that up :-)

Comment: The Guide to IP Layer Network Administration with Linux is outdated. No more route NAT in Linux 2.6 onward.

Answer (score 1):

I just implemented stateless NAT on a Debian/squeeze system based on a 2.6.32 kernel, I did not get it running with built-in features, but the `xtables-addons-*` packages that provide the `RAWSNAT` and `RAWDNAT` features were useful.

The `ip-route(8)` manpage contains a notice about route NAT no longer being supported in Linux 2.6.

Comment: `RAWSNAT` and `RAWDNAT` have been removed from `xtables`. Instead `tc` may provide a solution: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/249440/11-stateless-nat-kernel-version-3-16-or-later-using-tc/281800#281800?newreg=4f40eb3761fa498b9f0ecd06480a311b